# Partially Fill an array from a file

Tags: c++

I need to partially fill 2 arrays with data from a file and keep them parallel. But my current code gives me errors that look like giberish. If someone could even just help me decode the errors i would be very grateful.

Code:

```
/***************************************************/
/* Author:     Sam LaManna                         */
/* Course:     CSC 135 Lisa Frye                   */
/* Assignment: Program 6 Elves                     */
/* Due Date:   11/22/11                            */
/* Filename:   program6.cpp                        */
/* Purpose:    Write a program that will process   */
/*             the work done by santas elfs        */
/***************************************************/

#include <iostream>     //Basic input/output
#include <iomanip>      //Manipulators
#include <string>       //String stuff 
#include <fstream>      //File input/output

using namespace std;

void instruct ();     //Function Declaration for printing instructions 
void input (ifstream &infile, string names [50], int numoftoys[50]);    //Function declaration for getting data from file

int main()
{

  string names [50] = { };       //Array for storing names
  int numoftoys [50] = { };      //Array for storing the number of toys made

  ifstream infile("eleves.dat"); //Opens input file "elves.dat"

  instruct();     //Function call to print instructions

  while (!infile.eof())
    {
      input (names [50], numoftoys [50]);
    }

  cout << names << "\n" << "\n";

  cout << numoftoys << "\n" << "\n";




  return 0;
}




/***************************************************/
/* Name: instruct                                  */
/* Description: Prints instructions to user        */
/* Parameters: N/A                                 */
/* Return Value: N/A                               */
/***************************************************/

void instruct ()                                   
{
  cout << "\n" << "This program will calculate the toys made by santas elfs and assign" << "\n";
  cout << "a rating to each elf. It will also sort them and print average, min and max." << "\n";
  cout << "\n" << "Make sure you have a file named elves.dat in the same directory as";
  cout << "this porgram or you will recieve errors.";
  cout << "\n" << "\n";

  return;
}


/***************************************************/
/* Name: input                                     */
/* Description: Reads from file                    */
/* Parameters: N/A                                 */
/* Return Value: N/A                               */
/***************************************************/

void input (ifstream &infile, string names [50], int numoftoys[50])
{
  infile >> names >> numoftoy;
  infile.ignore ("\n");

  return;
}
```

Errors:
[image]

Direct Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mWryj.png

Comment: Let's have the errors as text please. And, really, this sort of "technical support" question is off-topic here but I'll cut you some slack since you tagged as `homework`.

Answer (score 2):

```
istream::operator>> has overloads for neither arrays of strings nor arrays of integers.
```

You'll have to read each string and each integer in one at a time. Originally posted by [@Seth Carnegie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/726361/seth-carnegie)

```
input (infile, names, numoftoys); //your call was completely wrong

infile.ignore ('\n'); //notice the char instead of string

infile >> names >> numoftoys; //this won't work like this but at least we fixed the declaration error
```

If you are allowed to use std::vector,  etc. We could provide a more C++ answer. Also please avoid using - `using namespace std;`

Comment: whats wrong with using namespace std; ? thats what i was taught to use

Comment: @SamLaManna Well you should give me the number of the teacher so I can call him. Check this for an answer : http://cboard.cprogramming.com/cplusplus-programming/117354-why-std-not-using-namespace-std.html

Comment: @SamLaManna: Once again highlighting the widespread poor teaching quality of C++ in the world. [Here's why](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c)

Comment: @SamLaManna it's a little more OK to do in source files, but not header files.

Comment: Also FailedDev, please add my answer to your answer so I can delete mine. Yours is more complete.